# EF blocks access to database table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have `CodeFirst` web app `MVC4+EF+SQLServer`. There is `Statistic` table with `DateStamp(DateTime)` column. The web app perform calculation(Where and Count) in `Statistic` table on every request like this

```
public IQueryable<Statistic> GetStatisticForCurrentMonthByIp(string ip)
{
   return _context.Statistic.Where(p => p.Ip == ip && SqlFunctions.DateDiff("mm", DateTime.UtcNow, p.DateStamp) == 0);
}
```

The method above called like this in controller

```
var statList = _statisticService.GetStatisticForCurrentMonthByIp(queueItem.Ip).ToList();
```

The problem is that sometimes I need to delete all records in `Statistic` table but web app locks the `Statistic` table. When I try to execute SQL in SQL Server it just freeze.

```
DELETE FROM Statistic
```

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: How is this function called? Since you are returning an IQuerably, you are not executing any actual query with only this method.

Comment: The code updated. I calling the method with ToList() to execute query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it just freeze

So you need to investigate blocking in SQL Server. A simple tool is [Activity Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879320(v=sql.105).aspx). This is a bit dated but still useful: [Understanding and resolving SQL Server blocking problems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224453).

What you will discover is that reads block writes and writes block reads, likely because of your isolation level (see [using new TransactionScope() Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful)).

Using bulk deletes is very problematic in production and always a cause of blockage. A better alternative is [`TRUNCATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx) if you really want to nuke the content. DELETE should be used in small batches not only to prevent exhaustive blocking, but also you are not going to cause massive log outage due to growth required to accommodate *each and every row deleted*.

> Any idea how to solve the problem?

Look into [Row Versioning-based Isolation Levels in the Database Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177404(v=sql.105).aspx). Make sure you do not use `new TransactionScope()`.

Comment: TRUNCATE did the trick! Also thank you for reading recommendations.